# Prevent Highlighting of CSS ::before Content

Tags: html, css, sass, webkit

I have used `::before` for my ordered and unordered lists in my application, but I find that my ordered lists only are highlightable, and that the highlight color cannot seem to be changed to match the rest of my application.

[image]

**What I'd like is to disable highlighting of these elements in Webkit.** Unfortunately that means `user-select` is not an option. Any thoughts?

**The CSS for the ::before elements**
**HTML**

```css
  ol li p:first-of-type::before {
        content: counter(li) ".";
        text-align: right !important;
        width: 28px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
        color: rgba(21, 95, 122, 0.8);
        font-size: 13px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        margin-left: -4px;
        font-weight: 700;
        user-select: none;
        line-height: 0px;
        background: none !important;
    }

    ul li p:first-of-type::before {
        content: "-";
        margin-top: -11px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 6px;
        padding-right: 19px;
        width: 1px;
        /* float: left; */
        transform: scaleY(1.4);
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
        color: rgba(21, 95, 122, 0.7);
        line-height: 0px;
        user-select: none;
        background: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<div data-slate-editor="true" contenteditable="true" autocorrect="true" spellcheck="true" style="outline: none; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;" role="textbox">
   <ol data-key="36">
      <li class="" title="" data-key="29">
         <p data-key="28"><span data-key="27"><span data-offset-key="27-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="" title="" data-key="32">
         <p data-key="31"><span data-key="30"><span data-offset-key="30-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="current-item" title="Current Item" data-key="35">
         <p data-key="34"><span data-key="33"><span data-offset-key="33-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <ul data-key="46">
      <li class="" title="" data-key="39">
         <p data-key="38"><span data-key="37"><span data-offset-key="37-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="" title="" data-key="42">
         <p data-key="41"><span data-key="40"><span data-offset-key="40-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="" title="" data-key="45">
         <p data-key="44"><span data-key="43"><span data-offset-key="43-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <p data-key="48"><span data-key="47"><span data-offset-key="47-0"><br></span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: include  the html to go with the styling..lets see how this actually works

Comment: Thanks for reading. I've added the HTML code.

Comment: My response edited it seems certain version of chrome are ignoring the user-select css property..answer edited for another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class named `list` to all list in in your `ol` tag and style as follows

```
.list{
user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
}
```

Snippet below

```css
ol li p:first-of-type::before {
    content: counter(li) ".";
    text-align: right !important;
    width: 28px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
    color: rgba(21, 95, 122, 0.8);
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    font-weight: 700;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 0px;
    background: none !important;
}

ul li p:first-of-type::before {
    content: "-";
    margin-top: -11px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 19px;
    width: 1px;
    /* float: left; */
    transform: scaleY(1.4);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
    color: rgba(21, 95, 122, 0.7);
    line-height: 0px;
    user-select: none;
    background: none !important;
}
.list{
user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
}
```

```html
<div data-slate-editor="true" contenteditable="true" autocorrect="true" spellcheck="true" style="outline: none; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;" role="textbox">
   <ol data-key="36">
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="29">
         <p data-key="28"><span data-key="27"><span data-offset-key="27-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="32">
         <p data-key="31"><span data-key="30"><span data-offset-key="30-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="current-item" title="Current Item" data-key="35">
         <p data-key="34"><span data-key="33"><span data-offset-key="33-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <ul data-key="46">
      <li class="" title="" data-key="39">
         <p data-key="38"><span data-key="37"><span data-offset-key="37-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="42">
         <p data-key="41"><span data-key="40"><span data-offset-key="40-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="45">
         <p data-key="44"><span data-key="43"><span data-offset-key="43-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <p data-key="48"><span data-key="47"><span data-offset-key="47-0"><br></span></span></p>
</div>
```

**Alternative two (seems to work well in chrome)**

add the following property to the div container holder all the ul and ol lists

```
unselectable='on' onselectstart='return false;' onmousedown='return false;'
```

Snippet below

```css
ol li p:first-of-type::before {
    content: counter(li) ".";
    text-align: right !important;
    width: 28px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
    color: rgba(21, 95, 122, 0.8);
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    font-weight: 700;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 0px;
    background: none !important;
}

ul li p:first-of-type::before {
    content: "-";
    margin-top: -11px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 19px;
    width: 1px;
    /* float: left; */
    transform: scaleY(1.4);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
    color: rgba(21, 95, 122, 0.7);
    line-height: 0px;
    user-select: none;
    background: none !important;
}
.list{
user-select:none !important;
-moz-user-select:none !important;
-webkit-user-select:none !important;
-o-user-select:none !important;
}
ol{
user-select:none !important;
-moz-user-select:none !important;
-webkit-user-select:none !important;
-o-user-select:none !important;
}
```

```html
<div data-slate-editor="true" contenteditable="true" autocorrect="true" spellcheck="true" style="outline: none; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;" role="textbox" unselectable='on' onselectstart='return false;' onmousedown='return false;'>
   <ol data-key="36">
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="29" unselectable='on' onselectstart='return false;' onmousedown='return false;'>
         <p data-key="28"><span data-key="27"><span data-offset-key="27-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="32">
         <p data-key="31"><span data-key="30"><span data-offset-key="30-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="current-item" title="Current Item" data-key="35">
         <p data-key="34"><span data-key="33"><span data-offset-key="33-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <ul data-key="46">
      <li class="" title="" data-key="39">
         <p data-key="38"><span data-key="37"><span data-offset-key="37-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="42">
         <p data-key="41"><span data-key="40"><span data-offset-key="40-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list" title="" data-key="45">
         <p data-key="44"><span data-key="43"><span data-offset-key="43-0">Item</span></span></p>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <p data-key="48"><span data-key="47"><span data-offset-key="47-0"><br></span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks repzero. Your solution didn't work, but it was similarly what I had tried. Knowing faulty thinking on my part was not to blame, I began to wonder if the issue was in `Electron` (webkit for the desktop) or perhaps in the editor I am using `Slate`

It turns out that what I actually needed was this, because the `::before` exists in a `contentEditable`:  `-webkit-user-modify: read-only;` I'm not sure why my unordered lists didn't need that set. Thanks very much for your help. Upvoted because your solution should work in most cases.

Comment: gr8.....Can you confirm on your side if those attributes are working in the second solution?

Comment: Unfortunately of the constraints of the editor I'm using, adding those attributes to the list items would be a bit tedious. Would those attributes not also effect the list's content? In this case, the word 'Item'

Comment: @repzero Chrome 57.0.2987.133 is respecting the user-select property on my macOS machine and on my Windows and Linux partitions.